# negative one times positive one is negative one

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is a question I was surprised that no one on this forum has asked(as far as my search went).
I gave a proof that negative times negative = positive.
But it relied on the assumption negative times positive = negative.

SO now I am asking myself how does one show this fact:

> > negative times positive = negative

I am guessing that maybe the axioms of the real numbers maybe able to help.

I am wondering if anyone has pondered this question.

A lot of people pondered the -1 x -1, but not this one.

Regards,

P

Comment: What is "negative", an integer, a symbol, a mouse? What is "positive"?

Comment: Harder is to prove that 1 > 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the equation $1\times-1$, we can use the following fact:
$$1\times A=A\quad\text{ for every }A$$
Substituting in $A=-1$, we get $1\times-1=-1$.

For the general case, consider $a\times-b$, where $a$ and $b$ are positive. We have:
\begin{align}
0&=a\times 0\\
&=a\times(b+-b)\\
&=(a\times b)+(a\times-b)
\end{align}
We know $a\times b$ is positive. Thus, $a\times-b$ must be negative, because otherwise, if it were positive, we would have $0={\rm positive}+\rm positive$, which is impossible.

Comment: How do you know 1 > 0? and how do you know that if b is positive that -b is therefore negative?  Okay, I'm being picky but if we are doing axioms....

Comment: Hi  Akiva, yes I like your proof. Using the multiplicative Identity of 1. And your general case if very good too! This proof of yours using the axioms seems to be the easiest of all. Thanks so much for this simple to understand proof!

Answer (score 3):

It's a standard proposition of the field axioms.

If $x> 0, y>0$ then $xy > 0$ is a field axiom.

If $x < y$ then $x + z < y + z$ is a field axiom.

For every $x$ there exists a unique $-x$ such that $x + (-x) = 0$.  Field definition.

Prop: If $x > 0$ the $-x < 0$ and vice versa.

Proof: $x > 0 \implies x + (-x) > 0 + (-x) \implies 0 > -x$.

Prop: $(-x)y = y(-x) = -(xy)$ (and $-(-x) = x$).

Proof $(-x)y + xy  = (-x + x)y = 0*y = 0$.  And $x(-y) + xy = x(-y + y) = x0 = 0$.  So $(-x)y = -(xy) = x(-y)$.

($ x + -x  = 0$ so $-(-x) = x$.)

Prop: if $x > 0$ and $y < 0$ then $xy < 0$.

Proof: $ (-y) > 0$  so $x(-y) = -xy > 0$.  $So -(-xy) = xy < 0$.

Answer (score 2):

$ (-1)1 = -1 $ because 1 is the multiplicative identity.

$$ x * -1 = x * ( 0 - 1) = (0x) - (1x) = \\ 0 - x = -x $$ by the distributive law.

Then you can generalize to $ x * -y $

$ x * -y = x * ( y * -1 ) = (x * y) * -1 = -(x * y) $

Comment: And what about $x * y$; $y < 0; y \ne -1$?

Comment: Edited to cover that case.